# In Hoard of the Dragon Queen, can Hazirawn influence or control its wielder?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I have a question about Hazirawn. Since the sword can talk and is neutral evil.  Can it influence the wielder, or control him/her eventually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, anything that can talk to someone can influence them. Just like any character, Hazirawn can influence its wielder by the simple expedient of giving them advice, or suggestions, or even just by chatting to them. This method relies solely on your creativity and powers of persuasion to roleplay Hazirawn well and manipulate your player into doing things.

While Hazirawn doesn't mention anything about taking over its wielder, it is a sentient item, and the DMG section on sentient items includes this paragraph on page 216:

> Conflict
>
> A sentient item has a will of its own, shaped by its personality and alignment. If its wielder acts in a manner opposed to the item's alignment or purpose, conflict can arise. When such a conflict occurs, the item makes a Charisma check contested by the wielder's Charisma check. If the item wins the contest, it makes one or more of the following demands:
>
> - The item insists on being carried or worn at all times.
> - The item demands that its wielder dispose of anything the item finds repugnant.
> - The item demands that its wielder pursue the item's goals to the exclusion of all other goals.
> - The item demands to be given to someone else.
>
> If its wielder refuses to comply with the item's wishes, the item can do any or all of the following:
>
> - Make it impossible for its wielder to attune to it.
> - Suppress one or more of its activated properties.
> - Attempt to take control of its wielder.
>
> If the sentient item attempts to take control of its wielder, the wielder must make a Charisma saving throw, with a DC equal to 12 + the item's Charisma modifier. On a failed save, the wielder is charmed by the item for 1d12 hours. While charmed, the wielder must try to follow the item's commands. If the wielder takes damage, it can repeat the saving throw, ending the effect on a success. Whether the attempt to control its user succeeds or fails, the item can't use this power again until the next dawn.

Hazirawn has an alignment listed, but if you want to use these rules, you will still need to decide on its Charisma score. Note that some of the lesser demands and consequences listed here may be just as useful for influencing a player as taking control of them. If Hazirawn's wielder has come to rely on its awesome power, threatening them with the loss of some or all of that power is highly likely to be an effective way to influence them.